# Aumentar a confiabilidade de números aleatórios

Tags: c, números-aleatórios

Tenho uma função que gera números pseudo-aleatórios com `rand` que tem um *seed* que é uma hora publicamente conhecida. Alterar a *seed* não é uma opção.

A aplicação necessita de um grau mais apurado de aleatoriedade, pois essa ordena uma sequência de elementos em uma lista e tal lista não pode, de maneira nenhuma, ser reconstruída. Pois o *seed* e a lista aleatória são públicos, dessa forma a reconstrução da lista inicial é possível. O resultado de uma lista ordenada pode ou não ser único.

A lista ordenada de forma "aleatória" também é pública. O ambiente da aplicação é Linux. Gostaria de saber como realizar isso com alguma outra função.

Comment: `srand` deve ser chamado apenas na inicialização do gerador. Qual sistema operacional? Se for Linux, utilize o `/dev/random` ou `/dev/urandom` provido pelo SO. Ou utilize o algoritmo Mersenne-Twister.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "grau mais apurado de aleatoriedade"? Há algum [teste de aleatoriedade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_tests) que a função `rand` não está passando? Ou talvez o [período](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?426941-What-s-the-period-of-rand%28%29) da função seja curto demais? Por favor especifique exatamente o que procura. O uso de `/dev/urandom` ou algum CSPRNG (se aplicável) ou talvez algum processo de mixagem pode ser uma boa ideia, ou não, depende muito de onde você quer chegar...

Comment: Tentei ser muito generalista e acabei tornando a pergunta vaga.

Comment: Melhorou, mas me explica melhor o que quer dizer com "tal lista não pode, de maneira nenhuma, ser reconstruída". Significa que após repetidos sorteios você não quer que volte à mesma lista? Ou entendi errado? Além disso, é importante pra você que o programa seja repetível, i.e. que dado o mesmo *seed* se chegue ao mesmo sorteio? Se a resposta for "não", então `/dev/urandom` é uma boa pedida (mas talvez não seja suficiente pros seus requisitos, esclareça o ponto acima por favor e talvez eu consiga responder algo).

Comment: Podes usar o [Mersenne Twister com inicialização melhorada](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/MT2002/emt19937ar.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa de uma função de hash.

Se entendi bem, sua lista final é `Li` e sua semente `s`, e a lista final `Lf` é dada por `Lf = f(s, Li)`. `Lf` e `s` são públicos, e você não quer que se descubra `Li` somente a partir de ambas as informações públicas apresentadas. Certo? Nesse caso, tudo o que você precisa fazer é com que a função `f` não seja **invertível** (i.e. dado seu resultado - sua *imagem* - você descubra suas entradas - sua *pré-imagem*).

Não se sabe se existem ou não funções não-invertíveis ([*one-way functions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function)), mas até hoje ninguém sabe como inverter eficientemente certas funções de hash. De modo que elas são uma boa candidata para resolver seu problema. Se você tiver acesso a alguma delas, digamos SHA-256, você pode usá-la para gerar uma sequência de números pseudo-aleatórios:

```
semear(Li, s) {
    sufixo = SHA-256(str(Li) + SHA-256(s))
    indice = 0
}

próximo número aleatório() {
    return SHA-256((indice++) + sufixo);
}
```

Pseudo-código: `str(Li)` é uma representação em string (ou bytes) da sua lista, e `+` no caso representa a concatenação. Também é necessário transformar a saída da função SHA-256 (que virá em bytes ou em string hexadecimal, normalmente) em um número usável.

O fato de eu ter chamado SHA-256 várias vezes dessa forma é pra evitar [*length extension attacks*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack), pode ser exagero, mas prefiro pecar pelo excesso de cautela... O fato é que cada vez que você pedir um novo número aleatório ele vai calcular o hash de um valor único, imprevisível sem o conhecimento de `Li`. E a saída de uma boa função de hash costuma ser indistinguível de um valor realmente aleatório.

P.S. Essa solução pode não ser a mais rápida de todas, mas preserva a propriedade desejada. De início eu pensei em simplesmente semear o `rand` com o valor do hash, mas aí me lembrei que é possível recuperar a semente do mesmo observando-se um número relativamente pequeno de valores gerados... De modo que não serve para o propósito. Outra alternativa que me veio à cabeça agora é usar um [CSPRNG](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSPRNG) semeado da mesma forma que no meu exemplo (uma combinação da lista original e do seu *seed*), não sei quais existem nem boas implementações dos mesmos em C, mas se você tiver acesso a um o desempenho certamente será melhor que essa minha solução *ad-hoc*...